# How can I get serial numbers in to a field in a jTable?

Tags: jquery, jtable

How can I get a serial number automatically in to a field in a jTable? Here's what I've got:

```
recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
  var SrNo = 0;
  if (data.records) {
    $.each(data.records, function (index, record) {
      var row = $('#RejectedPackingTypeTable').jtable('getRowByKey', record.packingTypeIdInRejectedGrid);   
      SrNo++;
      row.find('td:eq(0)').text(SrNo);
    });
  }
}
```

This code of my senior works pretty well, but I have no idea what's happening internally

Comment: i want to know about this line especially:-       row.find('td:eq(0)').text(SrNo);

Comment: The line of code that worries you, is inside a loop, walking through the table. The ```var row``` is being set to a jquery object for the row. The find function is selecting the td elements of the row, the pseudo selector ```:eg(0)``` is  reducing the selection to the element at index zero. In other word, the first td element of the row. You could equally write ```find('td.first')``` which may be more readable. Finally the ```.text()``` function is setting the text content of the td element to your incremented sequence number.